# Extra line in the post preview

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-preview

Currently when I type in a question or an answer here's how the preview looks like:

[image]

Note the dotted frame around the preview area. There's no extra space between the first line of text and the upper dotted line, but there's room for an extra line of text between the last line of text (there's no linefeed after it as you can see in the edit area) and the lower dotted line.

I suppose that's a bug and there should not be extra room between the last line of text and the lower dotted line the same way as there's no extra room between the first line of text and the upper dotted line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's just down to how `<p>` is styled. That input would simply be translated to:

```
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
```

Exploring the generated content in Firebug:

[image]

Comment: ... both in the preview and the final post. Precisely. There's no "extra line", there's whitespace.

Comment: @balpha: Whatever it is - whitespace or anything - it looks untidy IMO. Is there a need for it?

Comment: @sharptooth: yes, there is. It keeps the bottom of each paragraph from bumping up against the text below it. It looks very untidy *without* it!

Comment: @Shog9: Is it possible to maybe preserve that for all paragraphs except the last one in the preview?

Comment: Not reliably, @sharptooth, no.

Comment: A compromise would be to set both the top and bottom margins to half the height. That way you get the same gaps between paragraphs and smaller ones at the top and bottom of the whole text. But really, it's fine as it is.

Comment: Btw I believe that setting the top and the bottom to half (or maybe even third) the height would be a really good idea.